# Как поменять язык вывода даты/времени при создании запроса API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, локализация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поменять язык выдачи даты при POST запросе - регистрации пользователя на сайте.
Сейчас "На сайте с 28 November 2023", а нужно "На сайте с 28 ноября 2023".

Вот сериализатор

```
class UserProfileSerializer(UserSerializer):
   
    profilecustomer = ProfileCustomerSerializer(read_only=True)
    profiledesigner = ProfileDesignerSerializer(read_only=True)
    is_subscribed = SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    resume = ResumeReadSerializer(read_only=True)
    date_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    portfolio = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'is_subscribed',
            'photo',
            'date_joined',
            'is_customer',
            'profilecustomer',
            'profiledesigner',
            'resume',
            'portfolio'
        )

    def get_date_joined(self, obj):
        return f'На сайте с {obj.date_joined.strftime("%d %B %Y")}'
```

Comment: попробуйте импортировать модуль locale (`import locale`), а затем выставить русскую локаль в сериализаторе перед методом strftime:  `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "ru_RU"`.